# WicketTester: How to click secondary mouse button?

Tags: wicket

I want to test a wicket component which shows a context menu on click with the secondary mouse button.

With `WicketTester.click(Component)` I can click obviously simulate a click on a component. But how do I simulate a click with the secondary mouse button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WicketTester does not provide means to test JavaScript!

If the context menu is being shown with Wicket Ajax call to the server to make it visible then you can do `tester.executeAjaxBehavior(...)`.

If the menu is shown via JavaScript in the browser then WicketTester cannot check whether it is visible or not. But in that case you should be able to test selecting a menu item, i.e. sending an Ajax call with the appropriate value for the item.